# More effective way to convert file to byte array to string and back

Tags: java, string, file, arrays

I have following way of converting file to byte array and than to string and back.

```
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("c:/original.png"));
        String temp = Hex.encodeHexString(IOUtils.toByteArray(is));
        System.out.println(temp);
        byte[] b = Hex.decodeHex(temp .toCharArray());
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("c:/copy.png"));
        IOUtils.write(b, out);
```

It works OK. The problem is the size of `temp` string. If the `c:/original.png` file is `1523KB` than the `temp` size is `3046KB`. Is there more effective way of converting the file to the string that would not double the size of the file?  (BTW I understand why it is about  twice the size)

Alternatively, how would I go about compressing the `temp` string?

As far as the reason for the string. It is being stored in cache that will take only strings.  The file is actually upload to the web server. Once the upload is about to be downloaded it will be pulled from cache rather than the database. And the cache is there to improve search performance via predictions that I don't want calling the database each time someone searches.

Comment: Please could you clarify *why* you need to store the binary data in a `String`?

Comment: Why do you want it as a string?  Is it just to render on the screen?

Comment: Do you even need the hex encoded string? If not, skip that step and use the byte array directly.

Comment: You might try and compress the string somehow (RLE etc.), but since a single byte has to be represented by two hex digits there's no way to reduce the size of a plain copy.

Comment: Also, if it's just to make a copy, you don't need to store the whole file in memory. Read 2K bytes and write them, then read the 2K subsequent bytes and write them, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more efficient encoding than Hex is Base64, the overhead tending toward a minimum of about 37% for large files. Unfortunately there's no standard library for it, but Apache Commons contains a class to do this.

```
        String temp = Base64.encodeBase64String(IOUtils.toByteArray(is));            
        byte[] b = Base64.decodeBase64(s);
```

Comment: @Mat, two points: first - if you encoded/decoded correctly, you should get the input file back verbatim - not 50% bigger.  Second - the memory usage is still 3x the input size, because String chars are 16 bits.  I'm sure an encoding could be made that would use most of the unicode space and bring this down to near unity.  I can't find one off the shelf, though.